# Oracle SQL Error : 00909. 00000 - "invalid number of arguments" in SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

this is my first time using oracle Database in the company and I encountered this problem.

```
SELECT w.TABLE_NAME tbl_nm,
  MAX(CASE WHEN  t.partition_range LIKE 'year' THEN SUBSTR((w.PARTITION_NAME),1, LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-4) ELSE concat(SUBSTR((w.PARTITION_NAME), 1, LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-6)) END) AS par_nm,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.partition_range LIKE 'year' THEN SUBSTR((w.PARTITION_NAME), LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-3,4) ELSE concat(SUBSTR((w.PARTITION_NAME), LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-5,6)) END) AS par_date,
  t.partition_range par_range,
  t.data_dir data_dir,
  t.index_dir index_dir,
  t.add_range add_range,
  CASE WHEN t.partition_range LIKE 'year' THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM systimestamp) ELSE TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYYMM') END AS cur_date
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS w, t_partition_manage t
WHERE w.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY w.TABLE_NAME
```

when I Select `tbl_nm`,  `par_nm`, `par_date`, `par_range`, `data_dir`, `index_dir`, `add_range`, `cur_date` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` and `t_partition_manage`,

there seem to be a problem around in `MAX( ... )` and I don't know what is wrong...

This is the error code

```
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

and I'm using SQLDeveloper as a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with `concat` as it takes two parameters and You are passing only one parameter. `Concat` is not required at all in your solution:

```
SUBSTR(w.PARTITION_NAME, 1, LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-6)
```

And

```
SUBSTR(w.PARTITION_NAME), LENGTH(w.PARTITION_NAME)-5,6)
```

Also, you need more columns in `GROUP BY` as select can not use columns directly which are not in  `GROUP BY` clause or you can use aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `CONCAT`; it expects two parameters, while yours has only one.

```
CONCAT (SUBSTR ((w.PARTITION_NAME), 1, LENGTH (w.PARTITION_NAME) - 6))
```